# Query regarding instantiating of interfaces

Tags: java

I have a query regarding interfaces to confirm.

```
Interface interface1 = new Class(); //class implementing the interface
```

This creates an object of class `Class` and is pointed by the reference variable `interface1`.

However I was learning selenium and found that

```
Alert alert= driver.switchto().alert();
```

My query here is can we simply assign a reference variable to without instantiating (creating an object using new keyword) i.e

```
Alert alert= new RemoteAlert();
```

What's the difference between both ways?

Also can we do it for classes as well like:

```
Class class1 = object;
```

(without creating and using the new keyword) or is it applicable for interfaces only.

Just basically want to know why we use new keyword at some places and why we don't, especially for the selenium interface example I just posted.

Comment: You can assign an existing object or a new object. And a method can also return an existing object (or a new one created inside its code).

Comment: I don't like these questions... they usually involve a basic misunderstanding of specific coding principles that would take paragraphs to talk about completely. My problem is just with the huge discrepancy in these questions between "giving the fish" and "teaching how to fish".

Comment: IS this ir-respective for Class and interface? I mean can we do both Class class= object and Interface interface= Object. Also when we define a variable like this int xyz=object;. Are all these the same things? Some details would really help

Comment: Jashaszun, i completely understand, but you know how important are these when you don't have anyone to help you out. It would be great if you can get me out of this query

Comment: In your code for alert, you internally receive a new instance of it. think of it as a method that gets you a new instance without you having to create explicitly.

Comment: it would be helpful if someone can clear my basic query here: 
IS this ir-respective for Class and interface? I mean can we do both Class class= object and Interface interface= Object. Also when we define a variable like this int xyz=object;. Are all these the same things? Some details would really help